# Regex to pick the alias from email address

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds, non-greedy

I need to identify all email addresses in a given cell enclosed in any special character, written in any number of multiple lines.

This is something that I built.

```
"(!\s<,;-)[a-zA-Z0-9]*@"
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `[!\s<,;-][a-zA-Z0-9]*@[^\s@]+` https://regex101.com/r/KjZYeo/1

Comment: Please provide a few sample inputs and exactly what you what to match from them.

Comment: Example:
From xyz123@gmail.com I need the value, xyz123

Comment: Ok, doesn't `([A-Za-z0-9]+)@` work well enough for you?

Comment: But `xyz123@gmail.com` is not enclosed in any special character right? To get a match only `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=@)`

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(!\s<,;-)[a-zA-Z0-9]*@` starts with capturing `!\s<,;-` literally. If you want to match 1 of the listed characters, you can use a character class `[!\s<,;-]` instead.

If you want to match *xyz123* in *xyz123@gmail.com* you can use:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=@)
```

The pattern matches

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any of the listed ranges
- `(?=@)` Assert (not match) an `@` directly to the right of the current position

See a regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CyVMxj/1).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
([a-zA-Z0-9]\w*)@
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/9glmjx/1/)

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z0-9]              any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
```